# Xcode can't find paths that are there

Tags: xcode, ios, linker, directory

I have an xcode project that was created on another mac. That make was PROBABLY osx 10.5 using Xcode 3. (When I went to install xcode I could only get Xcode 4 AND was required to upgrade my mac to 10.6)  anyway, I am experiencing problems compiling this project that compiles fine on the other computer.

I don't know why. The build always fails and I see it is looking for a path incorrectly.

The physical directory layout is like this

```
/path/devfolder/devfolderMainProject/mainproject.xcodeproj
/path/devfolder/helpinglibrary/helpinglibrary.xcodeproj
/path/devfolder/anotherlibrary/anotherlibrariesFiles/...
```

But when Xcode starts doing the stuff for the helping library, it returns linker errors and I can see it is looking for files in the wrong places

```
linker error  /path/devfolder/helpinglibrary/../../anotherlibrary/anotherlibrariesFiles/src/correctfile.cpp  does not exist
```

so I browse and see that the file definitely does exist, and that Xcode is looking too many directory up

../../

should just be

../

so that it only goes 1 directory up, how do I make it look in the right place?

Moving the folders around in finder breaks plenty of OTHER things, so I am not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to open the target properties. In the "Build" tab, look for the settings `OTHER_LDFLAGS` and `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATH`. I have a project with a structure just identical to your one and I have edited these properties to inform the Xcode where to look for my libraries. Maybe you can have some wrong value in some of these settings.

Comment: Still no luck, I'm sure it has to be something similar to what you mentioned though! It still wants to recurse two directories higher, when it is supposed to only do one   `i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: /Users/RD/Documents/dcatomapps/bytemark_dev/ZXingWidget/../../cpp/core/src/zxing/BarcodeFormat.cpp: No such file or directory`